# Is there a canonical way to reorder the DACL of an object after adding an ACE to it?

Tags: c++, windows, acl

After adding an ACE to a file ACL, I checked the permissions on the object using Explorer.  It is giving me an error about the DACL not being in canonical format and asks me if I would like it reordered. Is there any sort of documentation anywhere that provides the canonical ordering of the DACL so I don't have to rely on explorer to reorder it every time?  Or (even better) an API function to do it for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the SetEntriesInAcl function (as opposed to low-level functions such as AddAce) the ACL will be put in canonical order automatically.

Comment: Great, that worked much better.  I was trying to do things with AddAce.  I didn't realize SetEntriesInAcl even existed.  Thanks!